# PROC SQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sas

I want to join two tables in SAS and I am using PROC SQL for it

I have **newdb.access_db** which has several **company codes** and **newdb.Company_Codes** having names of the corresponding company codes

I want the ouput in such a way that the resulting table will all the columns from newdb.access_db and the new column of company names  corresponding to company codes of each row

Following is my  code

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE newdb.access_db_with_company_name AS
SELECT newdb.access_db.*,newdb.Company_Codes.ENTITY FROM newdb.access_db
LEFT JOIN newdb.Company_Codes
ON newdb.access_db.ENTREPRISE_IDENTIFIER = newdb.Company_Codes.ENTREPRISE_IDENTIFIER;
RUN;
```

With this code I am getting syntax error

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, !, !!, &, *, **,
              +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, AS, BETWEEN, CONTAINS, EQ, EQT,
              FORMAT, FROM, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, INFORMAT, INTO, IS, LABEL, LE, LEN, LENGTH,
              LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, TRANSCODE, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.
```

Error points to

```
SELECT newdb.access_db.*,newdb.Company_Codes.ENTITY FROM newdb.access_db
                      -                         -
                      22                        22
                      200                       76
```

When I see my editor window in sas it say that code is running.I then hit `break` button to stop the code.

I am not getting whether what I have wrote is correct or not.Even if it is wrong then how the code is executing

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the tables:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE newdb.access_db_with_company_name AS
SELECT a.*b.ENTITY 
FROM newdb.access_db as a
LEFT JOIN newdb.Company_Codes as b
ON a.ENTREPRISE_IDENTIFIER = b.ENTREPRISE_IDENTIFIER;
RUN;
```

Comment: Just edit the table names with alias after `ON` as well.It works perfect

Comment: @Rookie_123, thanks and sorry I missed that.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever, you have more than one table in a query, you should use table aliases and qualified column names.  The aliases should be abbreviations for the tables, so the queries are easier to understand.

So, I would recommend:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE newdb.access_db_with_company_name AS
    SELECT a.*, cc.ENTITY
    FROM newdb.access_db a LEFT JOIN
         newdb.Company_Codes cc
         ON a.ENTREPRISE_IDENTIFIER = cc.ENTREPRISE_IDENTIFIER;
    RUN;
```